# How to send an audio file to Google Speech-to-Text from Firebase Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to send a small audio file (a few seconds) from Firebase Storage to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text, using Firebase Cloud Functions. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize) says to use this synchronous code for small audio files:

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const gcsUri = 'gs://my-bucket/audio.raw';
// const encoding = 'Encoding of the audio file, e.g. LINEAR16';
// const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
// const languageCode = 'BCP-47 language code, e.g. en-US';

const config = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: languageCode,
};
const audio = {
  uri: gcsUri,
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file
const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
  .join('\n');
console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);
```

That code doesn't run because it has `await` without `async`.

Another issue with this code is that it doesn't catch errors. Fixing these problems, and putting in the Firebase Cloud Functions trigger, I have this code:

```js
exports.Google_Speech_to_Text = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Pronunciation_Test/downloadURL').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    return async function syncRecognizeGCS() {
      // [START speech_transcribe_sync_gcs]
      // Imports the Google Cloud client library
      const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

      // Creates a client
      const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

      const gcsUri = 'gs://my-app.appspot.com/my-file';
      const encoding = 'Opus';
      const sampleRateHertz = 48000;
      const languageCode = 'en-US';

      const config = {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode,
      };
      const audio = {
        uri: gcsUri,
      };

      const request = {
        config: config,
        audio: audio,
      };

      // Detects speech in the audio file
      const [response] = await client.recognize(request)
      .catch((err) => { console.error(err); });

      const transcription = response.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');
      console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);
      // [END speech_transcribe_sync_gcs]
    }

  }); // close Google_Speech_to_Text
```

The function executes, returns `ok`, and nothing else:
[image]

There's no error message. I don't see anything wrong with the file in Storage:

[image]

I tried a different file, this time an `mp3`. Same result, except that the function executed in 17ms because the file was smaller.

I had trouble figuring out the audio encoding and sample Hertz rate that `mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` uses in Chrome. This [blog post](https://blog.addpipe.com/audio-constraints-getusermedia/) said the audio encoding is `Opus` and the sampling rate is `48000`. Sometimes I get an error `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..` The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/error-messages) says `Your audio data might not be encoded correctly or is encoded with a codec different than what you've declared in the RecognitionConfig.` Can `encoding` and `sampleRateHertz` be left empty and Google Speech-to-Text figures it out?

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the code provided by Google doesn't catch errors. When I refactored the code to use a promise instead of `await` I got an error message.

```js
exports.Google_Speech_to_Text = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Pronunciation_Test/downloadURL').onUpdate((change, context) => {
        // Imports the Google Cloud client library
        const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

        // Creates a client
        const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

        const gcsUri = 'gs://my-app.appspot.com/my-file';
        const encoding = 'Opus';
        const sampleRateHertz = 48000;
        const languageCode = 'en-US';

        const config = {
          encoding: encoding,
          sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
          languageCode: languageCode,
        };
        const audio = {
          uri: gcsUri,
        };

        const request = {
          config: config,
          audio: audio,
        };

        // Detects speech in the audio file
        return response = client.recognize(request)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);    
        })
        .catch((err) => { console.error(err); });
    });
```

The error was `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..` In other words, the audio encoder wasn't `Opus`.

Removing the line `const encoding = 'Opus';` results in the error message `encoding is not defined`.

Using `const encoding = '';` results in the error message `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..`

I need to figure out what audio encoder Chrome uses now. It's too bad Google Speech can't figure this out.

Comment: did you find a solution in the end @thomas-david-kehoe ? I am trying to accomplish the same

Comment: I'm trying to remember this. I was trying to set up Google Speech-to-Text with the user recording a short recording in Cloud Storage, then Cloud Functions sending the file to Google Speech-to-Text. I instead used a Cloud Function to connect Angular to Google Speech-to-Text in realtime, which resulted in janky connections. Now I'm working on connecting Angular to Google Speech-to-Text with a IAM service account, without the Cloud Function.